# General position is preserved under isomorphisms of algebraic varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I was reading the [General position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_position) article on Wikiepdia, and came across the following sentence:

> General position is preserved under biregular maps – if image points satisfy a relation, then under a biregular map this relation may be pulled back to the original points.

Can someone point me to a reference where this is stated and proved? I cannot find any. I tried looking in Harris's *Algebraic Geometry - A First Course* and in Shafarevich's *Basic Algebraic Geometry*.

And just to make sure I understand, is this what the sentence from Wikipedia is stating?

> Let $X \subset \mathbb R^m$ and $Y \subset \mathbb R^n$ be affine algebraic varieties and let $\phi : X \to Y$ be an isomorphism. Suppose $\{x_1, \ldots, x_k\} \subset X$ is such that for every $d \leq m+1$, no $d$ points of $\{x_i\}$ are not contained in an affine $(d-2)$-plane in $\mathbb R^m$. Then for every $d \leq n+1$, no $d$ points of $\{\phi(x_i)\}$ are not contained in an affine $(d-2)$-plane in $\mathbb R^n$.

(It seems like there's also a statement for projective varieties, but I think they are equivalent.)

EDIT: Thanks to Kenny Wong for pointing out that the statement above is not was is meant by the sentence from Wikipedia.

However, in this case, I am confused the argument that 5 points in general linear position determine a conic in $\mathbb R^2$. I thought this was the argument:

> Start with 5 points $\{x_i\} \subset \mathbb R^2$ in genereal linear position. Let $y_i \in \mathbb R^5$ be the image of $x_i$ under the Veronese embedding. **Since the Veronese embedding is an isomorphism onto its image, the points $\{y_i\}$ are in general linear position**. Hence, there is a unique affine hyperplane passing through these 5 points, which gives us the unique conic.

In the sentence in bold, don't we use the fact that the Veronese embedding preserves general *linear* position? Is this something special for the Veronese embedding (i.e., is not a property of all biregular maps)?

Comment: In this article, there is a distinction between "general linear position" and "general position with respect to more general algebraic relations". The statement about pulling back relations refers to the latter.

Comment: What does "algebraic relations" mean? Is it a set of polynomials? E.g., in the case of general linear position, would the set be all linear polynomials? And what does it mean to "pull back relations"?

Comment: Yes, a set of polynomials. If $f: Y \to \mathbb R$ is a polynomial on $Y$, then $f \circ \phi : X \to \mathbb R$ is its pullback to $X$.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question. There is still something I don't understand.

Comment: I think you want to assume that the five points in $\mathbb R^2$ are in "general quadratic position" (if that's even a phrase). Because linear relations in $\mathbb R^5$ pull back to quadratic relations in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: But isn't it true that general linear position in $\mathbb R^2$ is enough? The Wikipedia article says "A fundamental application is that, in the plane, five points determine a conic, as long as the points are in general linear position (no three are collinear)."

Comment: Good point! Sorry! I don't think I understand that argument about pulling back relations between $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R^5$. (The key is the a linear relation on $\mathbb R^2$ becomes a *linear* relation for the embedding in $\mathbb R^5$)

Comment: However, if three of your points in $\mathbb R^2$ obey the linear relation $ax + by + cz = 0$, and if your embedding is $[U:V:W:X:Y:Z]=[x^2, xy, y^2, xz, yz, x^2]$, then surely the images of these three points in $\mathbb R^5$ will obey the linear relation $aU+bV+cX = 0$?

Comment: Yes, but that only shows that those three points lie in a 4-plane, which is not enough to demonstrate non-general position. It is also true that $aV + bW +cY = 0$ and $aX + bY + cZ = 0$, so we know these three points lie in a 2-plane, but even that is not enough to conclude that these points are not in general position.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that if the five points obey a linear relation in $\mathbb R^2$, then they obey a linear relation in $\mathbb R^5$. Isn't that what is required here? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_points_determine_a_conic#Dimension_counting

Comment: 5 points in $\mathbb R^5$ are in general position iff they do not lie on an affine 3-plane. So I think this is the property we need to verify.

Comment: Good point! Yeah, I don't think I understand that argument on Wikipedia at all!

Comment: No worries. I was talking to a friend today who thinks the statement may not even be correct... I'll figure this out somehow.